# How to handle nested elements and just output one in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

This is the first time for me to handle XML with nested elements and     looking for advise. I need to transform the input XML to only output one     element in the XML output.

Here's my input XML to look like. I have two elements for `<ImageId>` and two elements for `<ReferenceNumber>`. I only need to output one `<ImageId>` and one `<ReferenceNumber>` which are the first two elements under the `<InquireCase>` tag.

If I do a `<xsl:copy-of select` it copies all the `ReferenceNumber` fields. I have a duplicate results of the `<ReferenceNumber>201801364201801364</ReferenceNumber>`. If I do , there's no value in the `<ImageId></ImageId>` element. I did `<xsl:apply-templates select="ImageId></xsl:apply-templates>`, but the XML output shows blank.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<InquiryRequest>
    <InquiryCase>
        <ImageId>123453453</ImageId>
        <ReferenceNumber>UDHD654634</ReferenceNumber>
    </InquiryCase>
    <Document>
        <Lastname>MOUSE</Lastname>
    </Document>
    <InquiryCase>
        <ImageId>123453453</ImageId>
        <ReferenceNumber>UDHD654634</ReferenceNumber>
    </InquiryCase>
</InquiryRequest>
```

Here's my XSLT so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
    xmlns:env ="urn:envision">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <msxsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"></msxsl:text>

    <xsl:template match="InquiryRequest">            
        <xsl:element name ="ImageId">
            <xsl:value-of select="ImageId"/>
        </xsl:element>                                            
        <xsl:element name="InquiryCase">   
            <xsl:element name ="ReferenceNumber">
                <xsl:copy-of select="//InquiryCase/ReferenceNumber/text()"/>
            </xsl:element>                          
        </xsl:element>   <!-- added by edit -->
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ImageId">
        <xsl:element name ="ImageId">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ImageId"></xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I added an `xsl:element` to make the XML of the XSLT _well-formed_.

Comment: How does your desired output look like?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is the following template. The `[1]` indicates the first `InquiryCase` element:

```
<xsl:template match="InquiryRequest">            
    <xsl:element name="InquiryCase">   
        <xsl:element name ="ImageId">
            <xsl:value-of select="InquiryCase[1]/ImageId"/>
        </xsl:element>                                            
        <xsl:element name ="ReferenceNumber">
            <xsl:copy-of select="InquiryCase[1]/ReferenceNumber/text()"/>
        </xsl:element>                          
    </xsl:element>   <!-- added by edit -->
</xsl:template>
```

**Output is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<InquiryCase>
   <ImageId>123453453</ImageId>
   <ReferenceNumber>UDHD654634</ReferenceNumber>
</InquiryCase>
```

Comment: zx485 you just solve my problem!!! You're my hero!!! Adding that InquiryCase[1]/ImageId worked.  If I understand this correctly it's looking for the first element of the ImageId. Please correct me if am wrong.

Comment: @Les: Glad I could help. It's looking for the first `InquiryCase` and selects its `ImageId`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the explanation @zx485

Comment: zx485  quick question. Let's say I have an element called  ReferenceNoList and under this element I have two the same child elements called ClaimNoList. But each child elements have different values. Let's say the first ClaimNoList has a value of |123|134|125|126| then the second ClaimNoList has a value of |1456|. How do I add the second ClaimNoList  at the end of the first tag ClaimNoList?  Is this possible? Something like this the output I am looking for |123|134|125|126| 1456

Comment: @Les: I'm surprised that you posted a new question as a comment, because you haven't accepted my previous(vulgo: this) answer. It would be of some value if you accepted this answer and asked your new question as a new answer. This suggestion is not made due to greed, but merely due to a lack of the layout of your new question. A new question would be better for this case.

Comment: My apology I must be confused. I think I replied to your last comment that your previous suggestion worked. So I thought I could just post a new question here under the comment since the new question is related to nested elements. Thanks for suggesting to post a new question showing the layout. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="InquiryRequest">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="InquiryCase"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="InquiryCase">
        <xsl:copy>
            <ImageId>
                <xsl:value-of select="ImageId"/>
            </ImageId>
            <ReferenceNumber>
                <xsl:value-of select="ReferenceNumber"/>
            </ReferenceNumber>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="InquiryCase[following-sibling::InquiryCase/ImageId =  current()/ImageId]"/>
You may also do like this.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Here's the final layout that resolves my issue
```

```
         <xsl:variable name="ImageId" select="descendant::ImageId"/>
          <xsl:variable name="connStr" select="concat(env:GetScriptingLookup('@Database'), 'Trusted_Connection=YES')" />
          <xsl:variable name="provider">System.Data.SqlClient</xsl:variable>

          <xsl:variable name="DateTime">
           <xsl:variable name="sqlXref"> 
   SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(13), GETDATE(), 108) AS 'CURRENT_DTTM' FROM IMAGES_DETAIL (nolock) WHERE IMAGE_ID = &apos;<xsl:value-of select="$ImageId"/>&apos;
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of select="env:ExecuteScalar($provider, $connStr, $sqlXref)"/>
              </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:template match="InquiryRequest">     `enter code here`       
                   <xsl:element name ="ImageId">
                      <xsl:value-of select="ImageId"/>
                   </xsl:element>

                  <xsl:element name="RequestDateTime">
                  <xsl:value-of select="$DateTime"/>
              </xsl:element>

                   <xsl:element name="InquiryCase">   
                      <xsl:element name ="ReferenceNumber">
                          <xsl:value-of select="InquiryCase[1]/ReferenceNumber"/>
                    </xsl:element>                       
            </xsl:element>  
          </xsl:template>   
      </xsl:stylesheet>
```